# getting token from cognito and caching in wso2 Enterprise Intigrator

Tags: caching, wso2, amazon-cognito, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I need to get a token from Cognito but I don't know how to get it through enterprise integrator. I have `client_id` and `client_secet` and endpoint also. But I 'm not able to get the token seems I'm not calling the endpoint properly with proper parameter.

> After getting the token I need to cache it till the token expires so I don't have to call again and again

here is the code I'm trying

```
<cache id="cache-sample" scope="per-host" collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator" timeout="5000">
    <implementation type="memory" maxSize="1000"/>
</cache>
<header name="client_id" scope="transport" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
<header name="client_secret" scope="transport" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
<header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
       <address uri="https://xcxxxxxxxxxx.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<cache scope="per-host" collector="true"/>
<respond/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/api/myService" name="myService-api" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/getToken">
        <inSequence>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var payload = mc.getPayloadXML();
                var log = mc.getServiceLog();
                var client_id = payload..*::client_id.toString();
                var client_secret = payload..*::client_secret.toString();
                mc.setProperty("client_id", client_id);
                mc.setProperty("client_secret", client_secret);]]>
            </script>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format/>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
            <property expression="fn:concat($ctx:client_id,':',$ctx:client_secret)" name="credentials" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode($ctx:credentials))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            <property name="FORCE_POST_PUT_NOBODY" scope="axis2" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
            <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <cache 
                collector="false" 
                hashGenerator="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator" 
                id="cognito-token" 
                scope="per-host" 
                timeout="3600">
                <onCacheHit>
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property expression="/" name="[usage-service-api]:: CHACHE HIT"/>
                    </log>
                    <respond/>
                </onCacheHit>
                <implementation maxSize="50" type="memory"/>
            </cache>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" uri-template="https://xxxxxxxxxxx.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <cache collector="true" id="cognito-token" scope="per-host"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

> For first Call cache miss will happen in that case it will call the endpoint and store it in the cache
>   for the second call and onwards till the time expires for the same call it will hit the cache i.e. **Cache hit** then It will respond from `onCacheHit` mediator

```
<onCacheHit>
    <respond/>
</onCacheHit>
```

and

> But after cache hit it will skip any execution of any statement written after `cache` Mediator. So **So keep it in some other sequence if you are writing in some sequence**
>   You can have more than one `resources` in API.

If you want to know how to call this API then see this [getting cognito acces_token with wso2 esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60560441/getting-cognito-acces-token-with-wso2-esb/60667064#60667064)

```
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="/" name="[usage-service-api]:: CHACHE HIT"/>
</log>
```

The above block of code logs the content of the cache on `CACHE HIT`