# getting cognito acces_token with wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, amazon-cognito, access-token, wso2-esb

I'm trying to get access token through AWS Cognito with client credentials but getting something else.

> I'm doing this in wso2 Enterprise integrator 6.1.0

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema/instance">
            <soapenv:Header>
                <Content-Type xmlns="">$1</Content-Type>
                <Authorization xmlns="">$2</Authorization>
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body/>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
        <arg value="Basic 2354sdfmdtrerkdfdgkeryryrtwdasr345345twsdfwsedtr34"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<log level="full"/>
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <endpoint key="validateUser-ext-ep"/>
</call>
<log level="full"/>
```

> after this the response i'm getting is like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sIGxhbiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWN1c3RvbWl6YWJsZSBtb2RhbC1jb250ZW50LW1vYmlsZSI+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2PgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgY2xhc3M9ImJhbm5lci1jdXN0b21pemFibGUiPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8Y2VudGVyPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvY2VudGVyPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvZGl2PgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC9kaXY+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJtb2RhbC1ib2R5Ij4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8cCBhbGlnbj0iY2VudGVyIj5BbiBlcnJvciB3YXMgZW5jb3VudGVyZWQgd2l0aCB0aGUgcmVxdWVzdGVkIHBhZ2UuPC9wPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxicj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvZGl2PgogICAgICAgICAgICA8L2Rpdj4KICAgICAgICA8L2Rpdj4KICAgIDwvZGl2Pgo8L2JvZHk+Cgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==</ns:binary>l
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I don't  know if I'm doing something wrong as in postman I sent the data same way I was getting the token there I passed the `Authrization` as `Basic dfudne4r49859dfnw34598sdfs` base64 endcoded(client:client_secret) and `Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in header  and in params I passed `grant_type: client_credential` for this I was able to get the token but when I tried in wso2 esb I got the above error 
the endpoint looks like  :`https://xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is the API to get the Access token and it returns the access token

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/api/myService" name="my-service-api" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/getToken">
        <inSequence>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var payload = mc.getPayloadXML();
                var log = mc.getServiceLog();
                var client_id = payload..*::client_id.toString();
                var client_secret = payload..*::client_secret.toString();
                mc.setProperty("client_id", client_id);
                mc.setProperty("client_secret", client_secret);]]>
            </script>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format/>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
            <property expression="fn:concat($ctx:client_id,':',$ctx:client_secret)" name="credentials" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode($ctx:credentials))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            <property name="FORCE_POST_PUT_NOBODY" scope="axis2" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
            <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" uri-template="https://xxxxxxxxxxx.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

> Call the above API  like this :

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <root>
                    <client_id>$1</client_id>
                    <client_secret>$2</client_secret>
                </root>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('client_id')"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('client_secret')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="ContentType" scope="default" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
<property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/api/myService/getToken"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
<script language="js">
    <![CDATA[ var tokenContainer = mc.getPayloadJSON();
        var log = mc.getServiceLog();
        mc.setProperty("Authorization_header", tokenContainer.access_token);]]>      
</script>
```

> The Response will  be

```
{"access_token":"LzSq94JoaUT2LwJlkEl35CXX0MdwqtUKIL8Wvi7dm4SqcSofR4xF5xBZre83MZXpHOr-Hg","expires_in":360,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

In last script mediator you can access the token Access token throught getting it by `mc.getPayloadJSON()` this will give the same response as shwon above